# Inderscience peer-Review Process

Tags: publications, peer-review, journals, paper-submission

I submitted my paper two months ago to an Inderscience journal. Well, this is my first experience with Inderscience publisher, so while checking my paper updates, I can not understand the meaning of “Peer-Review Process” information in the track section.

[Image of the track section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg5eM.png)

Is there anyone familiar with Inderscience who can explain to me this information :

-Are those 4 reviewers already begin reviewing? Or they did not yet accept to review the paper?

-Why there is no Reviewer 1 or 3?

-What is the meaning of the three columns in front of each reviewer?

-What is the significance of (Under review) in green colour?

Comment: Not sure how reliable this information is, but [at ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/I-submitted-an-article-to-an-inderscience-journal-and-after-months-i-get-this-review-progress-illustrated-in-the-picture-what-does-it-mean) someone writes the following: Green means that the review request was accepted already. The black ones (#2, #4 and #5) have not yet accepted the review request. I would infer from that that #1 and #3 have declined the request to review.